# Setting a JS conditional to block "today"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date

UPDATE:
I have been trying a few things and this is almost correct... the issue is that it affects EVERY day if the "today" schedule has no empty seats.

```
var toujitsu = waitings[0].split('-');
var waitingToujitsu = new Date(toujitsu);
var currentDate = new Date();
if (waitingToujitsu.getDate() === currentDate.getDate()) {

  return [false, 'ui-state-disabled'];

}
```

ORIGINAL:
I am currently working on a website that handles restaurant reservations with a waiting list for those which are fully booked. The site is made using Rails, but this calendar for diners to select dates is using the following JavaScript to determine how the waiting list appears:

```
for (var i = 0; i < waitings.length; i++) {
      var d = waitings[i].split('-');
      var waiting = new Date(d[0], (d[1] - 1), d[2]);


      if (waiting.getYear() == date.getYear() &&
          waiting.getMonth() == date.getMonth() &&
          waiting.getDate() == date.getDate()) {
            if (<%= @restaurant.waiting_flag %>) {
              return [true, 'ui-state-waiting'];
            } else {
              return [false, 'ui-state-disabled'];
            }
      }
  }
```

All dates in the past are "greyed out" and can not be selected. Waiting list days (currently fully booked) appear in black but can be selected.

What I am currently trying to do is set a stipulation which prevents diners from adding to a waiting list for today (from tomorrow onwards is fine, but joining today is too much of a problem if seats suddenly open up)

I need to use the `return [false, 'ui-state-disabled'];` line if the restaurant is fully booked for today as that prevents a user from doing anything on that date but cannot figure it out at all.

Absolutely any help or advice will be massively appreciated!

"waitings" comes from here:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  var holidays = [];
  var waitings = [];
  <% cache @restaurant.id.to_s << "/#{I18n.locale.to_s}/" << @base_date.to_s << '/' << @seats.map(&:cache_key).join('/') do %>
  <% 100.times do |f| %>
    <% target_date = @base_date + f.days  %>
      <% unless active_seats(@seats, target_date).count == 0 %>
      <% else %>
          <% if RestaurantHoliday.is_restaurant_holiday?(@restaurant.id, target_date) %>
            holidays.push('<%= target_date.strftime("%F")%>');
          <% else %>
            waitings.push('<%= target_date.strftime("%F")%>');
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: try this `waiting.getTime() === new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but should I include that inside the loop? I have tried in a few positions but cannot get the desired result - well out of my comfort zone here and it is extremely likely that I am just missing something basic

Comment: What is inside your array ? i mean what value `waitings` contain

Comment: Just updated the original post with that

Comment: Yes it will be inside loop something like this  `waiting[i].getTime() === new Date().getTime()`. if it now work try this. `var waitingDate = new Date(waiting[i]);`  than this `waiting[i].getTime() === new Date().getTime()`

Comment: It's almost perfect - on page load the default (today) has no options when there are no empty seats. Unfortunately clicking another date and then back to today makes the option available again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154956/discussion-between-vishal-and-kuwantum).

Comment: @Vishal— `waiting[i].getTime() === new Date().getTime()` will be true on exactly 1 millisecond of the day.

Comment: What is the value of `toujitsu`? *getDate* returns just the day number of the month, so `new Date(2017,0,1).getDate() == new Date(2018,0,1).getDate()` will return true even though the two dates are a year apart.

Comment: @RobG Yes , you are right. it was my mistake. thanks for correct it :)

Comment: @RobG "toujitsu" (meaning "on the day" in Japanese) is supposed to just be the first appearance of a day with no available seats. My thinking is if I can get that day to check as being equal to "today" and then have it blocked (if that makes sense?). The more I look at it, the more I think I am missing something very basic though.

(For context: I am less than 2 months into my first developer role so want to learn from this experience if I can!)

Comment: Some tips for using SO: reduce your code to the minimum that demonstrates the issue: the clearer the question, the quicker you'll get answers. Provide sample input and with expected and actual output. Include error messages if there are any. Only use one language at a time. E.g. what is the **value** of *toujitsu* (not its meaning), it seems to be an array, you can't pass that to the Date constructor and expect a sensible result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to see if a particular date string represents "today", then your question boils down to how to parse a string and see if it's "today". There are certainly answers here already but it's probably faster to just write a new one, then delete it when I find a decent duplicate.

You haven't provided any sample input so I'll have to guess. Given:

```
var toujitsu = waitings[0].split('-');
```

I'll assume that `waitings[0]` is a timestamp with values separated by "-", maybe "2017-09-23". So *split* will return array that is assigned to *toujitsu* as if by:

```
var toujitsu = ['2017','09','23'];
```

Then there is:

```
var waitingToujitsu = new Date(toujitsu);
```

When passed a single value, the Date constructor deals with it as described in [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-value), which is to say that it will first see if it's a Date object. If not, it will then coerce it to a primitive and go from there.

For an array, it will use *toString* so the above resolves to:

```
var waitingToujitsu = new Date('2017,09,23');
```

which will almost certainly (but not definitely) return an invalid Date. You might be tempted to use destructuring:

```
var waitingToujitsu = new Date(...toujitsu);
```

but not only isn't that safe on the web at the moment, it will set the month to the wrong value, so use (assuming YYYY-MM-DD):

```
var waitingToujitsu = new Date(toujitsu[0], toujitsu[1]-1, toujitsu[2] );
```

which will create a Date for the given values with the time component set to 00:00:00 in the host timezone. Then:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

creates a Date for the current instant in the host system with millisecond precision. So there's only 1:86,400,000 chance (about the same as winning PowerBall with a single entry) that it will be "equal" to *waitingToujitsu*.

To do the comparison, set its time to zero, which can be done in one call to *setHours*, setting the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to zero:

```
currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Now you can compare the time values of the Date objets. You can't compare the Dates directly as they're different objects and `==` and `===` will both return false. But you can compare the time values, e.g.

```
if (waitingToujitsu.getTime() === currentDate.getTime()) {
  /* the two dates are "equal" */
}
```

So a simple function might be:

```js
// See if date in format YYYY-MM-DD parsed as local
// is "today"
function isToday(s) {
  // Create a Date from s
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2]);
  // Create a date for 00:00:00 today
  var n = new Date();
  n.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // Return true if they're equal
  return +d == +n;
}
```

```html
Input date (yyyy-mm-dd)<input id="i0" value="2017-09-22"><br>
<button onclick="
  console.log(isToday(document.getElementById('i0').value));
  ">Today?</button>
```

At the risk of obfuscation, the function could be reduced to:

```
function isToday(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) == +new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2]);
}
```

Given that *setHours* returns the new time value and `+` will coerce the second value to a number.